# MySQL database: lua or python

Tags: python, mysql, lua

Under preferences(Menu)/general (Tab)/ Interactive GRT Shell Language: lua or python.

What is the difference?

I use **MySQL** for database and involve mostly binary.

Comment: What preferences? Where?

Comment: menu/edit/preference/general (tab)/Interactive GRT Shell Language: lua or python.

Comment: but which program? What menu is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mysql is a **database server** -- it doesn't have a menu. I think you mean [mysql workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) which is a visual database design tool. That option allows you to use lua scripting or python scripting to help you on the design of your database -- ***it is unrelated to what happens on the mysql server***. There are some examples on usage of the scripting provided by mysql workbench [here](http://wb.mysql.com/?page_id=664).